# How to apply a function to all elements in a column in a dataframe for faster results?

Tags: python, function, performance, optimization, lambda

I have a data frame with close to 2.5M rows. The structure of the data frame is as follows:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 3256772 | 54745 |
| 3256778 | 54779 |

I have to apply a PyProj function such that the following result is obtained:

| X | Y | X2 | Y2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3256772 | 54745 | 23.45 | -49.23 |
| 3256778 | 54779 | 23.50 | -51.24 |

Is there anyway to optimize this piece of code? The data frame i'm working on has close to 2.5 million rows thus the optimization matters.

I have written the following code for applying the function but it is taking forever to process the results.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

def convert(x1,y1):
    inProj = Proj('epsg:3857')
    outProj = Proj('epsg:4326')
    x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1,always_xy=True)
    return(x2,y2)


final[['X2', 'Y2']] = final.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(convert(row['X'], row['Y'])), axis=1)
```

Comment: Does your `PyProj` function support vectorization? (most likely not), then the most reasonable option might be to parallelize (see [pandarallel](https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/) for example)

Comment: @mozway: I'm pretty new to the PyProj function. Can I simply apply final.parallel_apply(function) to try it? 

I tried that but nothing was happening.

Comment: I had not seen you used `apply` on `axis=1`, then I'm afraid it's not possible

Comment: Lines 1 and 2 could (most likely) be cut out of convert function, they do not depend on input parameters. Take a look at documentation of the `transform` function, maybe `x1` and `y1` could be arrays, if so you could provide whole column of x's and y's

Comment: @dankal444 That worked. I passed x1 and y1 as arrays and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions in the comments, I passed the x1 and y1 input values as numpy arrays and got the results. The code executed in 4.1s which works for me.

For future reference for anyone looking, here's the code I used:

```
final['X2'],final['Y2']=transform(input_epsg,output_epsg,final[["X"]].to_numpy(),final[["Y"]].to_numpy(),always_xy=True)
```